# JWT signing requirements for ES256

Tags: javascript, algorithm, jwt, digital-signature, es256

I am trying to compile the final part of my singing by generating the signature for my JWT using ES256.

According to [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/introduction/), I can sign it with HMAC SHA256 - here is where I get a bit confused, if my header uses ES256 - does this mean I have to sign it using ES256 algorithm?

It is a requirement that I have to [ES256](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests).

```
{
"alg": "ES256",
"kid": "DSR74G",
"typ": "JWT"
}
```

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7518#section-3.4

Comment: If alg is ES256, then you are signing with ECDSA.  If alg is HS256, then you are signing with HMAC-SHA256.  Which do you need?  If you need to sign with one system and verify with other systems, then go for ECDSA.  If you need to sign and verify from only one system and that will not changed, then HMAC is fine.

Comment: I have to use ES256 AND use Google Scripts so - does this mean I have to use ECDSA to go with ES256?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RFC 7518 defines ([in section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-3.1)) the allowed pairings between "alg" values and the MAC algorithm. `ES256` *must be* paired with `ECDSA using P-256 and SHA-256` as the MAC algorithm.

Since you are facing a requirement from Apple to use ES256, that means you have to use ECDSA.

Comment: Hi @TML, can help me what is this ECDSA, a bit new on this part so would be helpful as I managed to get JWT worked using python PyJWT library and ES256 but not Google Apps script. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77624020/google-app-script-with-es256-is-unable-to-authenticate-for-appstore-connect-jwt

Answer (score 0):

We get "invalid client" when there is problem in your key or "sub" when verifying authorization code with ES256. Use the below code and your problem will be solved, as I have solved my problem.

Code:

```
private static CngKey GetPrivateKey()
    {
        using (var reader = File.OpenText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key2"].ToString()))  //put your key's path  like C:\ABC.p8
        {
            var ecPrivateKeyParameters = (ECPrivateKeyParameters)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
            var x = ecPrivateKeyParameters.Parameters.G.AffineXCoord.GetEncoded();
            var y = ecPrivateKeyParameters.Parameters.G.AffineYCoord.GetEncoded();
            var d = ecPrivateKeyParameters.D.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
            return EccKey.New(x, y, d);
        }
    }
   var utc0 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    var issueTime = DateTime.Now;

    var iat = (int)issueTime.Subtract(utc0).TotalSeconds;
    var exp = (int)issueTime.AddMinutes(55).Subtract(utc0).TotalSeconds;
    var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "sub", "com.xyzttt" },  // you registered app 
        { "aud", "https://appleid.apple.com"},
        { "iss", "ABCDEFGHttt" },  //Team id 
        { "exp", exp },   }, //current time + @@@@ 
        { "iat", iat } } // current time
    };
    var extraHeader = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
          { "alg", "ES256" },
          { "kid", "5ABCDEFGH123tt21"}, //key id
    };
    var sb = GetPrivateKey(); 

    var ecdsa = new ECDsaCng(sb);

    byte[] headerBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(extraHeader, Formatting.None));
    byte[] claimsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload, Formatting.None));


    var Rpayload = Base64UrlEncode(headerBytes) + "." + Base64UrlEncode(claimsBytes);
    var signature = ecdsa.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Rpayload), HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
    var data = Base64UrlEncode(signature);
    string token = Rpayload + "." + data;
   
    return token;
```

Comment: @n bajra. I understand from the apple documentation that the client secret must not include the Team ID (ref client_secret at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens) and gather from @sonisan (see https://github.com/sonisan/apple-token-revoke-in-realm) that this should instead be the key_ID.