# How to sign JWT with ES256 algorithm?

Tags: google-apps-script, jwt, app-store-connect, es256

I am trying to generate a JWT token for [appstore connect APIs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests) with **ES256** algorithm.

I have managed to call the APIs using python code JWT Token with below code.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import json
import time
import curlify
import jwt
import requests



def generate_access_token():

    # The path to your service account private key file
    PRIVATE_KEY_FILE = "private_apple_key"

    # The URL of the Apple token endpoint
    TOKEN_ENDPOINT = "appstoreconnect-v1"

    issuer_id = "fc7d6b48-0000-00000-00000-4e8230bfda8f".  //modified for security reasons

    key_id = "WL000000XAU" //modified for security reasons

    ALGORITHM = 'ES256'

    try:
        key = open(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE, 'r').read()
    except IOError as e:
        key = PRIVATE_KEY_FILE

    token_gen_date = datetime.now()

    exp = int(time.mktime((token_gen_date + timedelta(minutes=20)).timetuple()))

    jwt_token = jwt.encode({'iss': issuer_id, 'exp': exp, 'aud': TOKEN_ENDPOINT}, key,
                      headers={'kid': key_id, 'typ': 'JWT'}, algorithm=ALGORITHM).decode('ascii')

    # return access_token
    print("\n",jwt_token,"\n")
    return jwt_token


def get_user_list():
    access_token_value = generate_access_token()

    # Set the JWT token in the Authorization header.
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token_value}"}

    # Make a GET request to the Google Play Developer API.
    response = requests.get("https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps", headers=headers)
    # response = requests.get("https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/userInvitations?filter[username]='abc@gme.com'", headers=headers)

    print(curlify.to_curl(response.request))

    # Check the response status code.
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Success!
        contents = json.loads(response.content)

        # Do something with the users.
        print(contents)
    else:
        # Handle the error.
        print(response.status_code)
        print("\n", response.content)


get_user_list()
# generate_access_token()
```

**Issue:**: I want to use the Google appscript for the JWT and API calling so can make some automationed for updating Google Sheet. Due to security concerts I cant use python code for domain issue to share with google sheet with service account.

I was able to find this closest matched code executed to generate a token, however its not accepted by appstoreconnect and gives error as below.

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "status": "401",
            "code": "NOT_AUTHORIZED",
            "title": "Authentication credentials are missing or invalid.",
            "detail": "Provide a properly configured and signed bearer token, and make sure that it has not expired. Learn more about Generating Tokens for API Requests https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=api-generating-tokens"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my Google Appscript code and from my research I was able to find only RSA256, HS256 code and matching function `Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(toSign, privateKey)` with below code that is running successfully.

```
var appleCredentials = SecurityAdapter.getAppleCredentials();
  var issuerId = appleCredentials["issuer_id"];
  var key_id = appleCredentials["key_id"];
  var apple_p_key = appleCredentials["p_key"];

// ----- ======== ...... -------


const createJwt = ({ privateKey, data = {} }) => {
  // Sign token using HMAC with SHA-256 algorithm
 
   var appleCredentials = SecurityAdapter.getAppleCredentials();
   var key_id = appleCredentials["key_id"];
    
  const header = {
    alg: 'ES256',
    typ: 'JWT',
    kid: key_id,
  };

  const payload = {
    iss: "issuerId",
    exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 20 * 60,
    aud: 'appstoreconnect-v1',
  };

  // add user payload
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
    payload[key] = data[key];
  });

  const base64Encode = (text, json = true) => {
    const data = json ? JSON.stringify(text) : text;
    return Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(data).replace(/=+$/, '');
  };

  const toSign = `${base64Encode(header)}.${base64Encode(payload)}`;
  const signatureBytes = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(toSign, privateKey);
  const signature = base64Encode(signatureBytes, false);
  return `${toSign}.${signature}`;
};


const generateAccessToken = () => {
// Your super secret private key

var appleCredentials = SecurityAdapter.getAppleCredentials();
var key_id = appleCredentials["key_id"];
var privateKey = appleCredentials["p_key"];

var issuerId = appleCredentials["issuer_id"]; 

const accessToken = createJwt({
  privateKey,
  expiresInHours: 0.20, // expires in 6 hours
  data: {
    iss: issuerId,
    exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 20 * 60,
    aud: 'appstoreconnect-v1',
  },
  });
  Logger.log(accessToken);
};
```

*Diving further to research more:*  The below code JWT tokens generated was verified in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) and realised that the decoding is exact the same but the key size parts differ for the last section:

**Not Working JWT:**

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGci---------pZCI6IldMMkgzVzVYQVUifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJmYzdkNmI0OC1iZTRkLTRhYWE--------iLCJleHAiOjE3MDIwMDMyMTAsImF1ZCI6ImFwcHN0b3JlY29ubmVjdC12MSJ9.DzXbndN_1l1O1Kr111111111195Zje0_7UKs9FrZck0

**Working JWT:**

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGci---------pZCI6IldMMkgzVzVYQVUifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJmYzdkNmI0OC1iZTRkLTRhYWE--------iLCJleHAiOjE3MDIwMDMyMTAsImF1ZCI6ImFwcHN0b3JlY29ubmVjdC12MSJ9.R98fbDcwOfvMjGPJqFJAdYNLI1111111111Y0LUzFbNDq5dARTS7nja6LRB0Kw3Z1OEgcKuz2oV2MayB9HOMKg

The string is basically with HEADER.PAYLOAD.VERIFIY-SIG components, so the **VERIFY-SIG**  is not same size and this is where the doubt arise that the function in Google `computeHmacSha256Signature` cannot be used, is there any alternative or anyone tried.

Comment: You may try https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign by mocking the browser variables in server... Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/63647410/